# 2D array in F Sharp

Tags: arrays, function, f#, functional-programming

I have just started learning f# and developed a basic game however, at the moment you specify the cell to play on using a single array. For example to place an X or O on the middle cell, you would type 5 when promoted. I want to change this to accept 1,1

I have listed my source code for the game below

```
let  arrayOfCells = [|" "; " "; " "; " "; " "; " "; " "; " " ;" "|]


let drawGrid()=

    Console.Write("\n\n\t\t" + arrayOfCells.[0] + "|" + arrayOfCells.[1]+ "|" + arrayOfCells.[2] + "\n" )
    Console.Write("\t\t------ "+ "\n" )
    Console.Write("\t\t" + arrayOfCells.[3] + "|" + arrayOfCells.[4]+ "|" + arrayOfCells.[5] + "\n" )
    Console.Write("\t\t------ "+ "\n" )
    Console.Write("\t\t" + arrayOfCells.[6] + "|" + arrayOfCells.[7]+ "|" + arrayOfCells.[8] + "\n" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 2D array in F# using the `array2D` function, so to initialize the cells, you could use:

```
let cells = 
  array2D [
    [ " "; " "; " " ]
    [ " "; " "; " " ]
    [ " "; " "; " " ]
  ]
```

Now you can access elements using `cells.[0, 0]` and modify the values using:

```
cells.[1, 1] <- "X"
```

The indices are from 0 to 2 so if you want to iterate over all cells to draw the grid, you need:

```
printfn "-------------"
for x in 0 .. 2 do
  printf "| "
  for y in 0 .. 2 do
    printf " %s |" cells.[x,y]
  printfn "\n--------------"
```

This should give you all the information about 2D arrays, so that you can change the data structure in your game - there are other ways to improve this, but that's probably question for [the Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).